# Responsive, multi-handle HTML 5 or javascript range slider

Tags: javascript, html, range, responsive-design

I'm currently working on a responsive site and would like to employ a multi-handle range slider. I have worked with some javascript solutions that worked ok, but were not responsive.

I have considered the option of two html5 range inputs, which degrade gracefully to text inputs on older browsers. I would however, like to know if anyone has come across a javascript solution for a range slider with multiple handles, that works in responsive environments. Any ideas or tips?

Comment: Have you taken a look at jQuery UI yet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i used the [fd-slider polyfill](https://github.com/freqdec/fd-slider) / with modernizr-loader, it was usable on the ipad. further devices were not tested, because the small-screen version didn't used them.

Comment: I like this. I'll have to do more investigation, but excellent advice. Thank you.

Answer (score 12):

You could have a look at [noUiSlider](https://refreshless.com/nouislider/).

It supports touch on a bunch of devices, and it works well with responsive designs. There's no dependencies on jQuery etc.

**Disclosure:** I made it.

Comment: You should disclosure you connection to Refreshless.com

Answer (score 4):

Check out my [slider](https://github.com/maslick/radiaSlider) I've written for my personal use a while ago. 
It has both the [linear](https://maslick.neocities.org/slider-linear/) (horizontal/vertical) and [circular](https://maslick.neocities.org/slider-circular/) implementations, works on desktop and mobile, it is lightweight (~5Kb) and fully customizable.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Try jQuery range slider: http://jqueryui.com/slider/#range.

It's well supported among different browsers.

Answer (score 1):

These look really slick but I haven't tried them:

http://ghusse.github.io/jQRangeSlider/demo.html

http://razorfish.github.io/JS-Range-Slider/

Answer (score 0):

Multihandle slider composed of 2 native inputs, by Lea Verou [here](http://leaverou.github.io/multirange/)

Answer (score 0):

For those who still end up here, looking around for options, I came across this one:

http://vanderlee.github.io/limitslider/

It allows you to pass an array of values, and even style the gaps between via an array of options.